# Creating OSX App bundle while embedding Mono in a Windows Forms project

Tags: c#, macos, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to create a simple App bundle with MonoDevelop 3.0.2.

Create a new solution *Empty MonoMac project*. Add reference to *System.Windows.Forms*. 
Create a new class with the following code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MM2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            MessageBox.Show ("Hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

This runs perfectly from MonoDevelop. Then in the *Project Options* dialog box, select the *Mac OS X Packaging* screen. Check *Include Mono runtime in the application bundle*. I leave the other options on default (Platform is X86).

Build the bundle by selecting Build/Build all. This creates an MM.app bundle in the bin/Debug folder.

The packager didn't copy the *libgdiplus.dylib* to the bundle, so I have to do this manually. (Without this step the app cannot be started, and the console log clearly states that Mono couldn't find libgdiplus). I copied the file *libgdiplus.0.dylib* and the link *libgdiplus.dylib* from /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Libraries folder to the Contents/Resources folder of the app bundle.

Now the app bundle is self contained, it does not require the Mono runtime to be installed. When running, it displays the message box. But after clicking the OK button, and the program shuts down, the Mono runtime crashes. This is the stack trace from the Console log:

```
Native stacktrace:
6/8/12 6:11:43.089 PM [0x0-0x26026].com.yourcompany.MM2:    0   MM2                                                 0x000a072f mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 287
6/8/12 6:11:43.089 PM [0x0-0x26026].com.yourcompany.MM2:    1   MM2                                 0x000058de mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 334
6/8/12 6:11:43.089 PM [0x0-0x26026].com.yourcompany.MM2:    2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9435859b _sigtramp + 43
6/8/12 6:11:43.089 PM [0x0-0x26026].com.yourcompany.MM2:    3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
6/8/12 6:11:43.089 PM [0x0-0x26026].com.yourcompany.MM2:    4   CoreFoundation                      0x940e4e05 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 53
6/8/12 6:11:43.089 PM [0x0-0x26026].com.yourcompany.MM2:    5   Foundation                          0x9386ea2f -[NSAutoreleasePool release] + 131
6/8/12 6:11:43.089 PM [0x0-0x26026].com.yourcompany.MM2:    6   MM2                                 0x00002b52 main + 1458
6/8/12 6:11:43.089 PM [0x0-0x26026].com.yourcompany.MM2:    7   MM2                                 0x00002555 start + 53
```

Answer (score -2):

After you click OK the program should end.  The end of your main function is the end of the application.

If you have an event loop or do something - it won't auto end.